# Custom shape not being filled in Swifftui

Tags: swiftui, shapes

I have a requirement where I need to overlay custom shapes with one of them being filled. This is recurring pattern in my app so I've chosen to refactor the code and pass the fill color. I'm using a triangle and square for simplicity. My custom shapes  are more complicated. Here's code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    ShapeView(lineWidth: 1, fillColor: .blue)
      .padding()
  }
}

struct ShapeView: View {
  let lineWidth: CGFloat
  let fillColor: Color
  
  var body: some View {
    ZStack {
      Square()
        .stroke(lineWidth:lineWidth)
      Triangle()
        .stroke(lineWidth:lineWidth)
        .fill(fillColor)
    }
    .frame(width: 200, height: 200, alignment: .center)
  }
}

struct Triangle: Shape {
  func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
    var path = Path()
    
    path.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.minY))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.maxY))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.maxY))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.minY))
    
    path.closeSubpath()
    
    return path
  }
}

struct Square: Shape {
  func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
    var path = Path()
    
    path.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.minY))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.maxY))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.maxY))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.minY))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.minY))
    
    path.closeSubpath()
    
    return path
  }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    ContentView()
  }
}
```

The triangle is supposed to be filled but it's not. Why is it not filled?
[image]

Comment: Does your code even compile? I thought you could only use either stroke or fill, not both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to just fill it:

```
struct ShapeView: View {
  let lineWidth: CGFloat
  let fillColor: Color
  
  var body: some View {
    ZStack {
      Square()
        .stroke(lineWidth:lineWidth)
      Triangle()
        .fill(fillColor) // <<: Here!
    }
    .frame(width: 200, height: 200, alignment: .center)
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Unbelievable. I'm pretty sure that's how I had it originally and just added the stroke to  see if it made a difference. My bad. Thanks!

Comment: You can add stroke if you want! say you want fill blue and a stroke black! you can do it with overlay! like this: `Triangle().fill(fillColor).overlay(Triangle().stroke(lineWidth:lineWidth))`